# RPM upgrade does not uninstall previous version of the package installed

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, centos7, rpm-spec

I have two builds (Build1 and Build2) of the current version of an rpm package. I use 'rpm -U' (rpm upgrade) to install it.

Build1 works as expected, where the previous version is uninstalled after the new version is installed.

Build2 does not uninstall the previous version. This leaves both versions of the package on the system (Centos 7).

I am trying to find out what is causing this difference in behavior. I used the '-vv' option to output debug logs and it looks like Build2 does not even try to uninstall the previous version.

The spec file of each build is the same from what I can see and only the contents seem to differ slightly. The rpm does not have any pre, post, preun, or postun scripts.

What could be the possible causes of this behavior?

RPM log of Build1

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -Uvv --replacefiles --test TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544.Build1.i686.rpm
D: ============== TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544.Build168.i686.rpm
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages 0x400 mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name 0x400 mode=0x0
D: Expected size:     49531882 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(49531602)
D:   Actual size:     49531882
D: TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544.Build168.i686.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (8a8ce80e01a21687044ad204eb8c716b094c8a67)
D:  read h#     831 Header SHA1 digest: OK (2522c1bad2c533a5050dae7c73616694f7ef906a)
D:      added binary package [0]
D: found 0 source and 1 binary packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== +++ TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544 i686/linux 0x1
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#     119 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: /usr/bin/perl                                 YES (db files)
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#     782 Header SHA1 digest: OK (42344bef7cc874fd8d6d57f1aaefb016a658e600)
D:  Requires: ARandomPackage                                YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     663 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     663 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)                          YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     663 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1)                          YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     663 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3)                        YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     663 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libm.so.6                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     663 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0)                          YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     205 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(CGI)                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     237 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(DBI)                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     120 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(Data::Dumper)                            YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     778 Header SHA1 digest: OK (e43ae2964d2bdd1d6cced5d0df8e52f9cb8b63c0)
D:  Requires: perl(Test::MachineType)                      YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: perl(Test::NetworkAccessControl)             YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     119 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(strict)                                  YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1        YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1                YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1       YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadIsBzip2) <= 3.0.5-1             YES (rpmlib provides)
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== --- TestPKG-xxx-12.6.0-0.1041 i686/linux 0x1
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== recording tsort relations
D: ========== tsorting packages (order, #predecessors, #succesors, depth)
D:     0    0    0    1   +TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544.i686
D:     1    0    0    1   -TestPKG-xxx-12.6.0-0.1041.i686
D: installing binary packages
D: Selinux disabled.
D: sanity checking 2 elements
D: computing 880 file fingerprints
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Group 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Triggername 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Dirnames 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Installtid 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sigmd5 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sha1header 0x400 mode=0x0
Preparing packages...
D: computing file dispositions
D: 0x00000907     4096       548211       186053 /opt/test
D: 0x00000904     4096       451768       125466 /var
D: ========== +++ TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544 i686-linux 0x1
D: Expected size:     49531882 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(49531602)
D:   Actual size:     49531882
D: TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150810150544.i686: Header SHA1 digest: OK (8a8ce80e01a21687044ad204eb8c716b094c8a67)
D: ========== +++ TestPKG-xxx-12.6.0-0.1041 i686-linux 0x1
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sha1header
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sigmd5
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Installtid
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Dirnames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Triggername
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Group
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
[root@localhost ~]#
```

RPM log of Build2

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -Uvv --replacefiles --test TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.Build2.i686.rpm
D: ============== TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.Build182.i686.rpm
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:0x401
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages 0x400 mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name 0x400 mode=0x0
D: Expected size:     49755926 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(49755646)
D:   Actual size:     49755926
D: TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.Build182.i686.rpm: Header SHA1 digest: OK (770a488f2472bbe57ec211050d7b3bdddcdfaf73)
D:  read h#     831 Header SHA1 digest: OK (2522c1bad2c533a5050dae7c73616694f7ef906a)
D:      added binary package [0]
D: found 0 source and 1 binary packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== +++ TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053 i686/linux 0x2
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#     119 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: /usr/bin/perl                                 YES (db files)
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename 0x400 mode=0x0
D:  read h#     782 Header SHA1 digest: OK (42344bef7cc874fd8d6d57f1aaefb016a658e600)
D:  Requires: ARandomPackage                                YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      19 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6()(64bit)                            YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      19 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)                 YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      19 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libm.so.6()(64bit)                            YES (db provides)
D:  read h#      19 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)                 YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     205 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(CGI)                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     237 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(DBI)                                     YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     120 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(Data::Dumper)                            YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     778 Header SHA1 digest: OK (e43ae2964d2bdd1d6cced5d0df8e52f9cb8b63c0)
D:  Requires: perl(Test::MachineType)                      YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: perl(Test::NetworkAccessControl)             YES (db provides)
D:  read h#     119 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: perl(strict)                                  YES (db provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1        YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1                YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1       YES (rpmlib provides)
D:  Requires: rpmlib(PayloadIsBzip2) <= 3.0.5-1             YES (rpmlib provides)
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename 0x400 mode=0x0
D: ========== recording tsort relations
D: ========== tsorting packages (order, #predecessors, #succesors, depth)
D:     0    0    0    1   +TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.i686
D: installing binary packages
D: Selinux disabled.
D: sanity checking 1 elements
D: computing 464 file fingerprints
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Group 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Triggername 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Dirnames 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Installtid 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sigmd5 0x400 mode=0x0
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sha1header 0x400 mode=0x0
Preparing packages...
D: computing file dispositions
D: 0x00000907     4096       548193       186053 /opt/test
D: 0x00000904     4096       451768       125466 /var
D: ========== +++ TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053 i686-linux 0x2
D: Expected size:     49755926 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(49755646)
D:   Actual size:     49755926
D: TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.i686: Header SHA1 digest: OK (770a488f2472bbe57ec211050d7b3bdddcdfaf73)
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sha1header
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Sigmd5
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Installtid
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Dirnames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Triggername
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Obsoletename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Conflictname
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Providename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Requirename
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Group
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Basenames
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -Uvv --replacefiles --test TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.Build2.i686.rpm
D: ============== TestPKG-xxx-12.8.0-0.20150811055053.Build182.i686.rpm
.... [SNIP]
D:  read h#      19 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
D:  Requires: libc.so.6()(64bit)
```

While your second package filename is 'i686'. It is actually for x86_64 architecture according the Requires (see '(64bit)').

So rpm treat it as multilib and happily install i686 and x86_64 side by side.

Comment: Thank you, @msuchy.  

An .so file in the RPM file was indeed changed from 32bit to 64bit.  

Does this mean the rpmbuild command detects the difference when the RPM is created? Or does rpm detect the difference when it tries to do the rpm upgrade?  

Is it possible to configure the rpm so that it is not treated as multilib and still uninstalls the previous version?

Comment: I am trying to thing how this happen. You probably tried to build i686 version on x86_64 by direct calling rpmbuild. This is wrong. When you use mock, it will not happen. The usage is: mock -r epel-7-i386 your.src.rpm

Comment: We had directly swapped a 32bit binary for a 64bit binary in the rpm contents. The previous version that was installed on the system contained the binary as 32bit. I believe rpmbuild did detect the difference but only as part of its normal processing (it did not throw any errors). We support a 32bit and 64bit platform where we build our own source, but this particular binary does not come from us. You were a great help!

Comment: If we need to keep the 64bit binary in the new version of the rpm, but do not want it to be treated as a multilib package, how can this be done? Is there some configuration in the spec file we can use? I tried "Obsoletes" but this did not help.

Comment: For what it's worth, the change from 32bit to 64bit was a correction. It was not meant to be 32bit but the old version of the package can no longer be changed. So we want to keep the rpm files as-is, but prevent them from being treated as multilib.